# How to use require.js in my backbone project

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am new to backbone underscore and require.js.
I followed [this tutorial](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/) to create a project using backbone.js and underscore.js .

Then I want to add require.js to that project.
 This is what I modify in the theater.html :

```
<body>
<h1>My Theater</h1>
<script src="libs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

    <div id="mainContainer"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Add Item" id="butAddItem" />

    <script type="text/template" id="tmplt-Movies"> 
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="tmplt-Movie">
        <div>*******************************************************</div>
        <div><%= Id %> </div>
        <div><%= Name %> </div>
        <div><%= AverageRating %> </div>
        <div><%= ReleaseYear %> </div>
        <div><%= Url %> </div>
        <div><%= Rating %> </div>
    </script>
</body>
```

I added fews line of code to main.js file :

```
require.config({ 
   paths: { 
     jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.7.1', 
     underscore: 'libs/underscore', 
     backbone: 'libs/backbone' 
} });
```

Then I got 2 errors :

```
1. ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined , Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

This is main.js file :
    require.config({ 
    paths: { 
        jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.7.1', 
        underscore: 'libs/underscore', 
        backbone: 'libs/backbone' 
     } });

```
 var Theater = {
   Models: {},
   Collections: {},
   Views: {},
   Templates:{}
  };


  Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});


  Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Theater.Models.Movie,
     url: "data/movies.json",
     initialize: function(){
     console.log("Movies initialize");
   }
  });

  Theater.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Movies").html());

  Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $("#mainContainer"),
     template: Theater.Templates.movies,
     //collection: new Theater.Collections.Movies(), //Not needed

     initialize: function () {
       //_.bindAll(this, "render", "addOne", "addAll");
       this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
       this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
      },

      render: function () {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        this.addAll();
     },

    addAll: function () {
      console.log("addAll");
      this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },

    addOne: function (model) {
       console.log("addOne");
       view = new Theater.Views.Movie({ model: model });
       $("ul", this.el).append(view.render());
    }

   });


  Theater.Templates.movie = _.template($("#tmplt-Movie").html());
  Theater.Views.Movie = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  template: Theater.Templates.movie,
  //events: { "click .delete": "test" },

  initialize: function () {
      //_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'test');
      this.model.bind('destroy', this.destroyItem, this);
      this.model.bind('remove', this.removeItem, this);
  },

  render: function () {
      return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
  },

  removeItem: function (model) {
    console.log("Remove - " + model.get("Name"));
    this.remove();
  }
 });


Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "defaultRoute"  //http://localhost:22257/Theater/theater.htm
},

defaultRoute: function () {
    console.log("defaultRoute");
    Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies();
    new Theater.Views.Movies({ collection: Theater.movies }); //Add this line
    Theater.movies.fetch();
    console.log(Theater.movies.length);
}
});

var appRouter = new Theater.Router();
Backbone.history.start();

//This is a hack for demonstration  purposes
$("#butAddItem").click(null, function () {
    var movie = new Theater.Models.Movie(
    {
        "Id": "BVP3s",
        "Name": "Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King: Extended Edition: Bonus Material",
        "AverageRating": 4.3,
        "ReleaseYear": 2003,
        "Url": "http://www.netflix.com/Movie/Lord_of_the_Rings_The_Return_of_the_King_Extended_Edition_Bonus_Material/70024204",
        "Rating": "PG-13"
     }
  );

  Theater.movies.add(movie);
  console.log(Theater.movies.length);
});
```

And i have no idea how to convert the main.js and create a app.js file for using require.js.

Any idea please.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can try backbone boilerplate for this that could be a good starting point. https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate/wiki/Getting-started-overview

Comment: Thanks @Ajeet-HoneyDreams for your link, but I really want to configure the project that I post above.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your main.js does not support asyncronous loading of JavaScript files correctly. But without seeing main.js, one cannot tell.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa : I added main.js dear.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly...

```
<script src="libs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Could be

```
<script src="libs/require.js" data-main="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Secondly

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    deps: ['backbone','jquery'],
    paths: { 
        jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.7.1', 
        underscore: 'libs/underscore', 
       backbone: 'libs/backbone' 
    }
});

require(['app']);
```

And finally wrap your app.js in a define.

```
define(function () {

    Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});


    Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Theater.Models.Movie,
        url: "data/movies.json",
        initialize: function () {
            console.log("Movies initialize");
        }
    });

    Theater.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Movies").html());

    Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#mainContainer"),
        template: Theater.Templates.movies,
        //collection: new Theater.Collections.Movies(), //Not needed
        initialize: function () {
            //_.bindAll(this, "render", "addOne", "addAll");
            this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
            this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
        },

        render: function () {
            console.log("render");
            console.log(this.collection.length);
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            this.addAll();
        },

        addAll: function () {
            console.log("addAll");
            this.collection.each(this.addOne);
        },

        addOne: function (model) {
            console.log("addOne");
            view = new Theater.Views.Movie({
                model: model
            });
            $("ul", this.el).append(view.render());
        }

    });


    Theater.Templates.movie = _.template($("#tmplt-Movie").html());
    Theater.Views.Movie = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        template: Theater.Templates.movie,
        //events: { "click .delete": "test" },
        initialize: function () {
            //_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'test');
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.destroyItem, this);
            this.model.bind('remove', this.removeItem, this);
        },

        render: function () {
            return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        },

        removeItem: function (model) {
            console.log("Remove - " + model.get("Name"));
            this.remove();
        }
    });


    Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "defaultRoute" //http://localhost:22257/Theater/theater.htm
        },

        defaultRoute: function () {
            console.log("defaultRoute");
            Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies();
            new Theater.Views.Movies({
                collection: Theater.movies
            }); //Add this line
            Theater.movies.fetch();
            console.log(Theater.movies.length);
        }
    });

    var appRouter = new Theater.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();

    //This is a hack for demonstration  purposes
    $("#butAddItem").click(null, function () {
        var movie = new Theater.Models.Movie({
            "Id": "BVP3s",
            "Name": "Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King: Extended Edition: Bonus Material",
            "AverageRating": 4.3,
            "ReleaseYear": 2003,
            "Url": "http://www.netflix.com/Movie/Lord_of_the_Rings_The_Return_of_the_King_Extended_Edition_Bonus_Material/70024204",
            "Rating": "PG-13"
        });

        Theater.movies.add(movie);
        console.log(Theater.movies.length);
    });

});
```

You could switch out your version of backbone for `backbone-amd` which is a AMD compatible version available through [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower), and use [Lodash](http://lodash.com/) instead of Underscore. On top of that, you should start thinking about abstracting your backbone models, collections, views and router into separate files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got 3 errors in my console dear : 1.  `Error: Script error for: jquery http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
...,m){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.re...
require.js (line 8)`


2. `ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});
app.js (line 3)`

3.  `Error: Load timeout for modules: backbone http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
...,m){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.re...`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `baseUrl` param

Comment: If you want another point of view on how to structure an app with REquireJs and Backbone, see Christophe Coenraets' blog entry: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/building-modular-web-applications-with-backbone-js-and-requirejs-sample-app/ The app is hosted on Github

Comment: @PaulOsborne : I added `baseurl` but it still has 2 more errors 1. `ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});
app.js (line 3)`  2.  `Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery,backbone http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
...,m){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.re...
require.js (line 8)`

Comment: Updated the require config, try now.